# How to renew CA certificate using easy-rsa

Tags: ssl-certificate

I need to renew ca certificate. I use easyrsa. I know there is command `easyrsa renew foo`
but it works only with regular certificates. I can't see any option like  `easyrsa renew-ca` and `easyrsa renew ca` does not work.

How can I do it properly? Do I need to run `easyrsa build-ca` again?

Comment: You do understand that creating a new CA certificate and "renewing" a CA certificate is the same process?  TLS certificates cannot be renewed, they can be replaced with new certificates, before and/or as they exipire.

Comment: Yes I know, but how to do this using easy-rsa? `build-ca` wants to run init-pki again, what can it cause? Will it lost key?

Comment: Btw I have many remote clients, what should I do first before expiration? Should I firstly renew server's cert or client's certs? Can clients with older (but still valid cert) connect to server with newer cert (or vice versa)?

Comment: If I do it wrong I will lost connection to all clients and they are at far place and it will cost money to drive them all around the country.